# Database Peer to peer relationship

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, schema

I have a table case which has case Id case Name

```
caseId | CaseName
------ |---------
1      | Case 1
-------|-------
2      |Case2
-------|-------
3      |Case 3
-------|-------
4      |Case 4
```

I have a requirement where all these cases are related, something like this:-

```
1-2
1-3
1-4
2-3
2-4
3-4
```

How to store the records in an efficient way

Comment: You don't need to store it. It can be expressed as part of the Carthesian product of the self-join.

Answer (score 0):

Make another table. Case Id and Related Case Id columns should have same data type as Case Id in your first table.

```
Case Id   Related Case Id
1          4
2          4
2          3
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting my question. I gave up while trying to format it. How did you do it? Also, I was thinking on simillar lines,looking out any other efficient solution. I think this is the best approach. Thanks again for your help

Comment: For formatting, you can edit the question. select the code sample in there. Then click on { } icon in the text area menu. That means, selected text is required to be treated as code.

Comment: @Nrusingha - For formatting, you may want to find instructions on this web site itself. Do a search for "Stack Overflow" and "formatting" and see what it returns. Yes, it's that easy!

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a many to many relation, you can create a junction table with both columns as a foreign key to case.

case_relation (case_id_1, case_id_2). Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If `caseId` column have unique values

```
with t( caseId  )as (
select 1 from dual union all 
select 2 from dual union all 
select 3  from dual union all 
select 4 from dual  
) 

select t1.caseId, t2.caseId from t t1
cross join t t2
where
t1.caseId <  t2.caseId
```